# Is there any way to change HTML5 type="date" to use format like this "2 February 2015"?

Tags: html, date, datepicker

I need to send variables using get method, but the date format should be "dd-monthName-YYYY" just like "02-February-2015" for example.

> Can it be done using HTML5 type="date"?

If it can't, then how can i do that?

Comment: Dropdown of HTML5 date, is self explanatory. Still if you want to get month name then you could use jQuery Datepicker, visit: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="datefield" type="date" />

    <script>
        var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

        $("#datefield").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val);
            var d = new Date(val);
            console.log(d.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + '-' + d.getFullYear());
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Result:

```
2015-02-02
2-February-2015
```